# Replace Content Notes in bulk or replace ContentDocumentLink

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

We are looking for a way to either replace Content Notes in bulk (the wrong .txt files were linked, however the metadata is correct), or replace the ContentDocumentLinkIds while removing the old ones. Is there a way to do this in bulk?

Comment: You could achieve that by updating contentdocumentlink id. You would need to export current data and then populate current linkid record and then create another column with the target linkid. Upload the data using new column.

Comment: Hi Mahmood. Thank you for getting back to me. Is there any way to achieve this by updating the Content Note itself?

Comment: Also, to confirm, would it also be possible to update the ContentLinkId with the isDeleted set to 1 through Data Loader, thereby deleting the notes?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you take a look at [Doug Ayers Blog](https://douglascayers.com/adopting-files-and-enhanced-notes-in-lightning-experience/) on Enhanced Notes which includes links to his Github repositories for code he's written for various utilities to convert files to Notes, move Notes between objects and other things. I think you'll likely find what you need either from one of his blog posts or from looking at the code he has written.